# Get latest version of tag from SVN

Tags: c#-4.0, tortoisesvn

I’m going to create a tool to packaging some of SVN tagged files. Hence my approach is to give the SVN trunk path of the folder I need to package and tool will identify the latest tag location from that folder. So is there any way to get latest tag path of the trunk folder.

Eg: Let’s say my trunk folder is “abcd”. And I have tagged 2 times as follows.

```
abcd-1.0.0.1-QA
abcd-1.0.0.2-QA
```

So I need to get `abcd-1.0.0.2-QA` for my package.

I’m using `“TortoiseSVN 1.2.6, Build 4786 - 32 Bit”` and `MS VS 2010.`
I develop my tool by `C#`.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should look for the highest SVN version number of your tags. you can use `svn info` on your tag local folders and parse the returns stdout for the "Revision" statement (use perl)

Comment: Thank you NirMH. Unfortunately this should develop by C#. So is their any way to do it by C#.

Comment: @Chanritha: try installing collabonet subversion library. it gives a command line based API you can use via your C# app to perform the above

Comment: Thanx again. Ill try that and let you know.

Comment: @Chanritha: if my answer helped you, I'll appreciate if you can accept it (click on the "vi" sign next to it)